# Group Policy WIzard for windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

is there a nice foolproof group policy wizard?
I am looking for a program that a none-technial user can run and will allow to create a group with very specific parameters step by step.

Comment: GPEdit is as simple as it gets, what exactly are you looking for?
If you need to give him control over specific options then please write them here.